# Load another application (calculator) to a layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, calculator

I am working on an online mock test application. I need to add calculator app of the device to a layout of my activity like this. 
[image: Manually developed calculator]

Currently I am using a calculator developed by myself. But now I have needed to add a scientific calculator. Therefore I have a thought to open calculator app on a linearlayout. I couldn't find enough resources to achieve this requirement. 
Please help me with this. Thanks in advance. ☺️

Comment: You cannot load other applications (Activity instances in particular) into your layout.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please suggest me a way to achieve this.

Comment: Well, a good starting point would be the [source](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_calculator) of the calculator app (or a [backported version](https://github.com/rahulparsani/material-calculator) of that. You might want to convert it from using an `Activity` to preferably a `Fragment`, then display that `Fragment` wherever you want.